# How do you pass a value to a hidden form field when a certain option is selected?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and cannot find an easy-to-understand answer. 
I would like a certain value to get passed to a hidden field when a user selects a certain option from the select dropdown.

I know that there are if/else statements but I'm not sure if that would be used in this situation.

For example: I have a select dropdown of a list of states.

```
        <select name="HomeState" required>
            <option value="1">Alabama</option>
            <option value="1">Alaska</option>
            <option value="1">Arizona</option>
            <option value="1">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="5">California</option>
            <option value="1">Colorado</option>
            <option value="1">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="1">Delaware</option>
       </select>
```

As you can see, any option other than California will be rated at a value of 1.

I would like it to where if the user selects the option of California, then the value of $300 will get passed to a hidden form field.

```
<input name="AmountNeeded" type="hidden" value="300" />
```

If they select anything other than California, the hidden field would get passed $100

```
<input name="AmountNeeded" type="hidden" value="100" />
```

How would I implement this logic? Would it be using if/else statement? I am new and don't exactly know how to set that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep this simple you could assign **ids** to the `<select>` and hidden `<input>` and listen to the change event via **`onchange()`** on the `<select>` with a function call.

And based on the selected item, change the value of hidden input.

**NOTE:** To test the snippet out I have removed the `type="hidden"`. **Do place it back.**

```js
function homeSelected(){
const home = document.getElementById("homeSelector").value;

if(home == 5){
document.getElementById("amountNeeded").value = 300;
}else{
document.getElementById("amountNeeded").value = 100;
}
}
```

```html
<select id="homeSelector" name="HomeState" onchange="homeSelected()" required>
  <option value="1">Alabama</option>
  <option value="1">Alaska</option>
  <option value="1">Arizona</option>
  <option value="1">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="5">California</option>
  <option value="1">Colorado</option>
  <option value="1">Connecticut</option>
  <option value="1">Delaware</option>
</select>

<input id="amountNeeded" name="AmountNeeded" value="100" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Easy to understand too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

```
<select name="HomeState" required onChange=myFunction(this)>
     <option value="1">Alabama</option>
     <option value="1">Alaska</option>
     <option value="1">Arizona</option>
     <option value="1">Arkansas</option>
     <option value="5">California</option>
     <option value="1">Colorado</option>
     <option value="1">Connecticut</option>
     <option value="1">Delaware</option>
</select>
```

Javascript code is:

```
<script>
function myFunction(x) {

  val =  x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;

  if(val == 'California')
    document.getElementsByName("AmountNeeded")[0].value = 300
 else
    document.getElementsByName("AmountNeeded")[0].value = 100
}
</script>
```

If else statement is good for you if you are sure that All other states have value 1 except **California**. If all states may have different values like some states may have 1 or some may have 2 or some may have 3, then there may be other alternatives to solve this like you can pass give one more attribute ***data-src-amount*** to options and give amount to ***data-src-amount***. You can create options like `<option value="1" data-src-amount="100">Alabama</option>` and in script, you can fetch data-src-amount on select change event instead of if-else statement.

Comment: Thank you! This helped!